# Zend Framework Sessions Being Lost

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I'm using sessions to store items in a shopping cart. I *can* create and persist sessions, but with some strange problems:

1. When I close the **tab** in Firefox (not the entire browser), the session appears to have been lost. Sometimes it doesn't happen though but usually it does.
2. Every single time I refresh the page or go to another page, the session ID changes to a new one. I've confirmed this by looking in the cookie with my browser, and also on the server.  Also, there are a max of 4 sessions stored on the server at one time. Is all this normal behavior?
3. The sessions seem to be lost at random intervals...it could be a few minutes or more than an hour.

I just followed the Zend manual but no luck in solving any of this. In the bootstrap I also have Session::start() and Session::rememberMe(). I'm using normal file storage for sessions, just storing in /var/lib/php5 which I think is where Zend framework likes to put it.

Thanks for any direction

Comment: are you using cookies for sessions or http only?

Answer (score 1):

If the session data is persisting but the ID is changing then there is a chance there is a call to [session_regenerate_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this before, and you will want to do something like this where you start your session at, for me this is in my Bootstrap.php

```
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['PHPSESSID'])) {
        Zend_Session::setId($_REQUEST['PHPSESSID']);
    }

    Zend_Session::start();
```

This should solve the issue.  When a user has a session, it typically gets passed with every request.

Answer (score 0):

Check your garbage cleanup time for PHP - `session.gc_maxlifetime`.  If it's short, it deletes your session files from under your nose and makes it appear "random".

The default value is 24 minutes (1440 seconds)

This should be set to (or greater than) whatever your cookie lifetime (`session.cookie_lifetime`) is set for in your application.